# Como aplicar DropDownListFor com bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho o seguinte de código:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.AvailableCountries, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
```

Resultado: https://s24.postimg.org/ppjhp3gqt/07_Jan_03_00_56.jpg

Quero deixar ela algo parecido com isso: https://s27.postimg.org/ksp1989c3/08_Jan_03_01_00.jpg

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver dessa maneira:

Usar : https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#customize-menu

Depois alterar o código:

Isso:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.AvailableCountries, 
                             new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
```

Para:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.AvailableCountries, 
                            new { @class = "form-control selectpicker", @readonly = true })
```